# java graphics paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have three classes - TableApp/Diner/TablePanel.
I don't quite understand how the graphics class works. I would need to send a Graphics object reference to my paintComponent from my main method but i'm not sure how to link it together. Any explanation on how would be so helpful!

#### TableApp Class

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class TableApp{
  public static void main(String[]args){    
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  TablePanel table = new TablePanel();
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setSize(500,500);  //I dont understand how to send my paintComponent a                    reference of a Graphics object
  } 
}
```

#### TablePanel Class

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TablePanel extends JPanel{

  Diner diner1,diner2,diner3,diner4,diner5,diner6;

  public TablePanel(){
    diner1 = new Diner(50,50,300,1,"Murray",Color.blue);
    diner2 = new Diner(50,50,300,1,"Murray",Color.blue);//will change once program runs
    diner3 = new Diner(50,50,300,1,"Murray",Color.blue);
    diner4 = new Diner(50,50,300,1,"Murray",Color.blue);
    diner5 = new Diner(50,50,300,1,"Murray",Color.blue);
    diner6 = new Diner(50,50,300,1,"Murray",Color.blue);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));
    setBackground(Color.white);


  }
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){//need call from main
    super.paintComponent(g);
    diner1.draw(g);
    diner2.draw(g);
    diner3.draw(g);
    diner4.draw(g);
    diner5.draw(g);
    diner6.draw(g);
  }

}
```

#### Diner Class

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Diner{
      private int X,Y,diameter=50,seatNumber;
      private String name;
      private Color colour;

      public Diner(int x,int y,int d,int sN,String n,Color col){//construct
        X=x;
        Y=y;
        name=n;
        diameter=d;
        name=n;
        colour=col;

    }
      public void draw(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillOval(X,Y,diameter,diameter);
        }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Forget what you are trying to ***do*** for a moment, what are you trying to ***achieve?***  And by that I mean, what would it be as expressed as a 'feature' to an end user.  What *feature* are you trying to offer the user?

Comment: You do not call `paintComponent()` yourself, Swing calls it when the component needs to be rendered.

Comment: *"would need to send a Graphics object reference to my paintComponent"* Why?  `paintComponent` will be called on your behalf by the repaint engine, which is responsible for creating/maintaining a valid graphics context.  Once added to the container, `Diner` will be painted automatically...

Comment: @MadProgrammer - this is a lab for class. The lab instructions said to 'set up a paintComponent method that takes a Graphics object as a parameter'. I don't understand how to get the images to draw without sending that method a reference. When the program runs an empty java window pops up. Shouldn't my main be calling atleast one of the outside methods?

Comment: @Quigg15405 Can you include the `Diner` class - it's not making sense so far :P

Comment: @Quigg15405 why edit your post to remove SSCCE?

Comment: You need to read some kind of introductory article/tutorial/book about Swing, you're not going to make or understand a Swing+Java2D application if you don't grasp the basic concepts :/

Comment: @DavidKroukamp  Huh.  Thanks for the heads-up.  I rolled it back.  Strictly speaking, an SSCCE must be 1 single source file, but that code is it is now appears to be at least 'short, complete & compilable'.

Answer (score 4):

- You dont call `paintComponent(..)` if needs be simply call `repaint()` which will refresh the container by calling `update(..)`, `paint(..)`, `paintComponent(..)` etc.
- In your code you never add the `TablePanel` `table` to your `JFrame` which you should do to make it visible via `add(..)`
- Also a diameter of `300` for each `Diner` and the same `x` and `y` co-ordinates of `50x50` would paint all `Diner`s on top of each and the `TablePanel` with a preferred size of `200x300` would not fit all the table(s) in. So basically the co-ordinates need reworking and/or panel size needs changing.
- You should not call `setSize(..)` on `JFrame` rather implement correct `LayoutManager` and/or override `getPreferredSize()` to fit contents of drawings on `JPanel` (note not good practice to use `setPreferredSize(..)`) and than call `pack()` after adding components and before setting `JFrame` visible.
- Remember to create and manipulate Swing components on `Event Dispatch Thread` via `SwingUtilities.invokeXXX` block.
- And how about some `Graphics2D` and `RenderingHints` to make those circles look perfect :)
- A further enhancement which I have not shown is using a `List` to add (via a method call in `TablePanel` like `addDiner(Diner d)`) and keep track of all the `Diner` class instances you add to the `TablePanel`. This you would simply iterate over the list in `paintComponent` rather than redundant lines of code.

Here is your code with above mentioned fixes:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TableApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                TablePanel table = new TablePanel();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(table);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class TablePanel extends JPanel {

    Diner diner1, diner2, diner3, diner4, diner5, diner6;

    public TablePanel() {
        diner1 = new Diner(10, 90, 20, 1, "Murray", Color.blue);
        diner2 = new Diner(70, 30, 20, 1, "Murray", Color.blue);//will change once program runs
        diner3 = new Diner(50, 60, 20, 1, "Murray", Color.blue);
        diner4 = new Diner(100, 90, 20, 1, "Murray", Color.blue);
        diner5 = new Diner(80, 120, 20, 1, "Murray", Color.blue);
        diner6 = new Diner(100, 30, 20, 1, "Murray", Color.blue);
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {//need call from main
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        diner1.draw(g2d);
        diner2.draw(g2d);
        diner3.draw(g2d);
        diner4.draw(g2d);
        diner5.draw(g2d);
        diner6.draw(g2d);
    }
}

class Diner {

    private int X, Y, diameter = 50, seatNumber;
    private String name;
    private Color colour;

    public Diner(int x, int y, int d, int sN, String n, Color col) {//construct
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        name = n;
        diameter = d;
        name = n;
        colour = col;

    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2d.fillOval(X, Y, diameter, diameter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't pass a Graphics object to paintComponent. This will be done and called by Swing (as someone said) when you add the component to your frame. So what you're not doing in main is the following

```
frame.add(table)
```

Once you add the component to your frame, it will be drawn on the frame.

Comment: Thank you! It's drawing a big blue circle :D